# Can I define the hostname (or other variable) on the vagrant command line?

Tags: vagrant

I want to do something like this:

```
vagrant up --hostname="hello.world"
```

However there's no `--hostname`.

The reason I want this is so that the provisioner (Ansible) can use it to modify the provisioning depending on the hostname.

I could also use `vagrant up hello.world` (in which case Ansible could use it as `inventory_hostname`), but in that case I'd need to create an entry for `hello.world` in the `Vagrantfile`, which I don't want, since all possible hosts use the same `Vagrantfile` configuration. (An alternative could be to somehow specify in the `Vagrantfile` "use this configuration regardless of vm-name", but I don't know how to do that either.)

If none of this works, I could use an environment variable, but I don't know how to process that in `Vagrantfile` either.

Answer (score 1):

You can call vagrant like:

```
HOSTNAME=myhostname vagrant up
```

In your Vagrantfile, store the environment variable:

```
$hostname = #{ENV['HOSTNAME']}"
```

And then call your ansible playbook passing [extra_vars](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common#extra_vars):

```
ansible.extra_vars = {
  hostname: "#{$hostname}"
}
```

Alternatively, if these hostnames are predefined in groups in your playbook you can use [limit](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_common#limit):

```
ansible.limit = "#{$hostname}"
```